# Is there any way for all detected malware of type "HackTool" to be automatically allowed in Microsoft Security Essentials?

Tags: windows, malware, ms-security-essentials

I research this sort of thing and don't really want it to be quarantining the hacking tools as malware, because they aren't really.

Answer (score 2):

Well I mean you can go into the MSE settings and just exclude a directory, is that a good enough compromise? I suppose it wouldn't work if a hacktool you happen to have was actually infected, though.

As far as I know you can't get it to exclude a *class* of threat, merely a filetype or file/location.